# Using Python smtilib.SMTP can't access to Gmail [WinError 10060]

Tags: python, smtplib

Finally i find the way to fix this issus:

## add `173.194.193.108 smtp.gmail.com` into the *hosts* then it works

I am a Newbie to use smaplib.SMTP, following the book i set the codes as below:

```
smtp=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
smtp.starttls()
print(smtp.ehlo())
```

but there's no response from the server,i try another server

> `smtp=smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com')`

then i get the response but only the gmail get the error

```
> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the
> connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
> established connection failed because connected host has failed to
> respond
```

by the way my browser can access the gamil, i not sure what cause this `[WinError 10060]` error.

Comment: Your browser accessing gmail has nothing to do with the smtplib accessing gmail.  Are you sure port 25 isn't being blocked in your network or your ISP isn't blocking port 25.

Comment: Could you tell me how can I check the port 25 whether blocked in my network?

Comment: @M_Sea https://www.siteground.com/kb/check-port-blocked-isp/

Comment: God,my smtp.gmail.com:25 is blocked in my network,Can i use other to access it???

Comment: Ask your network administrator!