# why do i get a timeout error when using smtplib on vscode and other editors but get a smooth run on replit?

Tags: python, smtplib

I try using the smtplibin python to send email and it once worked properly but of recent, it stopped working and i got this error

I tried my code in replit and it ran smoothly but when i try running it in VScode or any other editor, it gives that error message

```
import smtplib
my_email = "<email>@gmail.com"
password = "password"

connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
connection.starttls()
connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email,
                    to_addrs="receive@gmail.com",
                    msg="Testing mail")
connection.close()
print("done")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\pythonProject\AngelaYu 100DaysOfCode\SMTPLIB\Birthday Wisher\birthday-wisher-extrahard-start\main.py", line 49, in <module>
    connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 851, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 836, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party
```

Comment: This isn't a python problem, but rather a network problem. Check this duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826707/using-python-smtilib-smtp-cant-access-to-gmail-winerror-10060

Comment: You left out the rest of the error message.